# Map Entity Relationships using Fluent APIs - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have Following Entities in Application.

```
Student
Parent (This Parent can be Father/Guardian)
Address
```

They have following classes defined.

```
public Class Student
{
    public int StudentId {get; set;}

    //Addresses
    public Address TemporaryAddress {get;set;}
    public Address PermanentAddress {get;set;}

    //Parent
    public Parent Father {get;set;}
    public Parent Guardian {get;set;}
}

public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    //Addresses
    public Address TemporaryAddress {get;set;}
    public Address PermanentAddress {get;set;}

}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId {get;set;}
    public string Country  {get;set;}
    public string State  {get;set;}
    public string Town  {get;set;}
    public string House#  {get;set;}
}
```

And i want to have following sort of relationship between them

```
Student
        ->TemporaryAddress (Address)
        ->PermanentAddress (Address)
        ->Father           (Parent)
                ->TemporaryAddress (Address)
                ->PermanentAddress (Address)
        ->Guardian         (Parent)
                ->TemporaryAddress (Address)
                ->PermanentAddress (Address)
```

In other words,

Student has one **TemporaryAddress** and one **PermanentAddress**.
Student has one **Father** and one **Guardian** (They both can be same i.e. a Guardian can be Father as well)
Parent (Father/Guardian) has TemporaryAddress and PermanentAddress.

How can i acheive this **using Fluent APIs of Entity Framework**? What other fields needs to be added in **Address and Parent Entities** to make this relation possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Google your thread title and you will get [your answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the classes you have provided with Entity Framework creates the necessary tables and relations and from your question it is not entirely clear what problems you are facing. However, I assume that you want `Parent` and `Address` relations to be non-optional as opposed to the default relations created by Entity Framework that are optional.

You can use the fluent API to specify that a relationship is required. Here it is specified that a `Student` requires a non-null value for the `Father` property:

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Student>()
  .HasRequired(p => p.Father);
```

Entity framework will by default add cascading delete to a foreign key relationship so deleting say a `Parent` row will delete the associated `Address` rows. However, as you can reuse `Parent` and `Address` rows you have to turn this off. This can be done for the entire `DbContext` by removing the `OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`.

Putting this together you can create a `DbContext` using the fluent API:

```
public class Context : DbContext {

  public IDbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

  public IDbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

  public IDbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder
      .Entity<Student>()
      .HasRequired(p => p.Father);
    modelBuilder
      .Entity<Student>()
      .HasRequired(p => p.Guardian);
    modelBuilder
      .Entity<Student>()
      .HasRequired(p => p.PermanentAddress);
    modelBuilder
      .Entity<Student>()
      .HasRequired(p => p.TemporaryAddress);
    modelBuilder
      .Entity<Parent>()
      .HasRequired(p => p.PermanentAddress);
    modelBuilder
      .Entity<Parent>()
      .HasRequired(p => p.TemporaryAddress);
  }

}
```